# Many-to-many relationship with composite keys in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, mapping, composite-key

Is there a way to use `@JoinTable` annotation, connecting each table by two fields? Here are the example tables:

```
+----------------+  +----------------------------------+  +----------------+      
| example_table  |  | example_table_to_some_type_table |  | some_type_table|
+----------------+  +----------------------------------+  +----------------+   
|example_table_id|  |example_table_id                  |  |some_type_id    |
|another_id      |  |some_type_id                      |  |another_id      |
|...             |  |another_id                        |  |...             |
|other columns   |  +----------------------------------+  |other columns   |
|...             |                                        |...             | 
+----------------+                                        +----------------+
```

For a many-to-one case it would look like that:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumns({ @JoinColumn(name = "some_type_id", 
    referencedColumnName = "some_type_id", 
    insertable = false, updatable = false),
               @JoinColumn(name = "another_id", 
    referencedColumnName = "another_id", 
    insertable = false, updatable = false) })
private SomeType someType;
```

But what about many-to-many relationship? I tried the following and it didn't work:

```
@ManyToMany(targetEntity = SomeType.class)
@JoinTable(name = "example_table_to_some_type_table", 
    joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "example_table_id"),  
                    @JoinColumn(name = "another_id") }, 
    inverseJoinColumns = { 
                    @JoinColumn(name = "some_type_id"),  
                    @JoinColumn(name = "another_id") })
private Set<SomeType> someTypeSet;
```

I got the following error:

```
Repeated column in mapping for collection: com.package.name.Example.someTypeSet column: another_id
```

What should I look at and which part of this mapping is incorrect? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your join table needs 4 columns. 2 to reference the PK columns of `example_table` and 2 other to reference the PK columns of `some_type_table`.

So it should look like

```
+----------------+  +----------------------------------+  +----------------+      
| example_table  |  | example_table_to_some_type_table |  | some_type_table|
+----------------+  +----------------------------------+  +----------------+   
|example_table_id|  |example_table_id                  |  |some_type_id    |
|another_id      |  |example_table_another_id          |  |another_id      |
|...             |  |some_type_id                      |  |...             |
|                |  |some_type_table_another_id        |  |                |
|other columns   |  +----------------------------------+  |other columns   |
|...             |                                        |...             | 
+----------------+                                        +----------------+
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you please explain why do I need 4 columns? 2nd and 4th in your example would then contain the same values. And should the @JoinTable look pretty much the same to the one I wrote for this case or is it totally wrong?

Comment: No they wouldn't. You have a row in the left table with the ID [A, B], and a row in the right table with the ID [C, D]. So, to be able to reference these two rows, you need A, B, C and D. Your join table definition would be fine if you didn't repeat the same column twice.

Comment: I see your point and this table actually might work, but in my case there are really [A,B] and [C,B] (well, I didn't design those prerequisites, just need to work with them). So even if this works, I would have duplicated data. What do you think about this situation in general?

Comment: Unless you can guarantee that all the rows in both tables always have the same value in the another_id column (in which case this column is completely unnecessary), you will need 4 columns in your join table.